# How to deploy Symfony3 Application on CentOS

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, symfony-3.2

I still cannot understand what happening in my server
when i push my code throught the server in /public_html and wanna get the homepage of my application like this:

> http:/www.example.com/web/

Server shows me the content of /web (**the files and directory that exist inside /web**)

and that's happen after i follow step's Command Line to deploy symfony 3 in that link: 
https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/deployment.html

I Still cannot understand what's happening there!!

any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1-)
`yum install nginx`

2-)`service nginx start`

3-) Add Nginx configuration into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/project_name.conf`

```
server{
    set $web_host "domain_name";
    set $web_root "web_directory";

    server_name $web_host;
    root $web_root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
#    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
#        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
#        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
#        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
#    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

4-) `chmod -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html/project``

5-) `service nginx restart`and `service php-fpm restart`